# Unable to open process with xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I fail to start apache on windows because port 80 and 443 are blocked by some process.
Using `Netstat -a -n -o` I could get the process blocking it, but that gets me no further.
I know that is is asked very often, but the answers I found so far are mostly useless.

I changed all entries of port 443 into 553 in `httpd-ssl.conf` but that changed nothing.

EDIT:
Using TCPView I can see that a httpd server runs on the blocking processes. Using the task manager I can find out that this is located at `C:\xampp\apache\bin`. This means the apache blocks itself?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see 80 and 443 ports in my cmd too.
I had this problem before. By default skype uses this ports for incoming connections. I turned off listening 80 443 in skype settings and worked for a while, but after few days ports was blocked again.
It turned out that I receiving internet connection from getway machine who uses this port 80. I cannot see what thing uses this port because it's not actually on my computer.

I fix it like this:
Just changed port 80 to 8099 in httpd.conf and using localhost:8099 in net browser.

Comment: Skype was not the problem. I had configured skype not to use these standard ports.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a restart of the system. Somehow xampp had already started the httpd process but complained that it can not start the httpd process since the ports are blocked (by httpd from xampp).

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1.** Sometimes Skype, IIS or some other applications can block default port that Xampp uses. 
So you need to either stop them or change ports in Xampp.

**Case 2.** In my case Xampp had started two instances simultaneously. My localhost was working fine but Xampp Control Panel was showing error that ports are blocked. In this case Restart system and it should work fine.